# Compare json with regex in python

Tags: python, json, regex

I've got lots of test cases/events(JSON files) that I need to compare and show any changes. So what I've done is, I ran the events twice and replaced all changes with regex. I need to write a complete python script, which when run, checks all key/value pairs and lets me know what changed.
I've searched a lot but can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

Following is a snippet of my JSON files, original and with regex included:

```
{
  "_index": "activities-2019-09-05-000001",
  "_type": "ActivityRecordsType",
  "_id": "E0E6DD54-9AF1-DAE6-A80D-BC58C52F14C1::96864DBA-E8C1-44DC-B083-502679E35167",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "Destination_File_Drive_Encryption": "No Encryption Detected",
    "Source_File_Hash_Digest": "4bfa69b2d340292d48842b84352ba9d3aa49e077"
    }
}
```

```
{
  "_index": "activities-\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}-000001",
  "_type": "ActivityRecordsType",
  "_id": "E0E6DD54-9AF1-DAE6-A80D-BC58C52F14C1::\\w{8}-\\w{4}-\\w{4}-\\w{4}-\\w{12})",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "Destination_File_Drive_Encryption": "No Encryption Detected",
    "Source_File_Hash_Digest": "\\w{40}"
    }
}
```

Could someone provide me with a proper solution for this problem?
I could of course write a function maybe to identify if these are equal according to the keys of each value. But I think there might be a better way of doing it, specially with the regex involved. Something like this:

```py
def match_dicts(self, baseline_event, actual_event):
    match = False
    mismatch_count = 0
    for baseline_key in baseline_event:
        #print baseline_key
        if baseline_key in actual_event:
            #print baseline_key
            base_txt = str(baseline_event[baseline_key])
            actual_txt = unicode(actual_event[baseline_key])
            # Checking for plain value attribute
            if base_txt == actual_txt:
                match = True
             # Checking for the non-empty attribute
            elif "[ne]" in base_txt:
                if actual_txt is not None:
                    match = True
                else:
                    mismatch_count += 1
```

By putting in identifiers like `[e]` and `[ne]`

Answer (score -1):

i used nice package called `jsondiff`

example:

from jsondiff import diff

diff({'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'b': 3, 'c': 4})
{'c': 4, 'b': 3, delete: ['a']}